# How do I apply a function within `mutate_at` that conditions rowwise on values in other columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise

I have a data frame within which I would like to transform the values of one set of columns, conditional on values in another set of columns in the same row. I am trying and failing to do this in the `tidyverse` with a combination of `rowwise` and `mutate_at`. Here's a reproducible example.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(20912)
dat <- data.frame(cat1 = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 10, replace = TRUE), cat2 = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 10, replace = TRUE), id = 3, sim_1 = rnorm(10), sim_2 = rnorm(10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> dat
   cat1 cat2 id      sim_1       sim_2
1     A    A  3 -0.1054062 -0.47563580
2     B    A  3 -1.7198921  0.76713640
3     A    B  3 -0.5946627 -0.33958464
4     B    B  3 -1.6547488 -0.13026564
5     B    B  3 -0.3779149  1.29590315
6     B    B  3  0.6271939  0.08707965
7     B    B  3  1.6376711  1.02151753
8     A    B  3  1.7675520  1.66983954
9     B    A  3 -0.3284081 -1.28175621
10    B    B  3  0.8431148 -0.15415091
```

In that table, I want to transform the values of all columns that begin with `"sim_"`, conditional on the values of `cat1` and `cat2`. Say, for example, I want to replace the values in all the `"sim_*"` columns with `NA`, but only in rows where `cat1 == cat2`. So my expected result would be:

```
   cat1 cat2 id      sim_1      sim_2
1     A    A  3         NA         NA
2     B    A  3 -1.7198921  0.7671364
3     A    B  3 -0.5946627 -0.3395846
4     B    B  3         NA         NA
5     B    B  3         NA         NA
6     B    B  3         NA         NA
7     B    B  3         NA         NA
8     A    B  3  1.7675520  1.6698395
9     B    A  3 -0.3284081 -1.2817562
10    B    B  3         NA         NA
```

I tried a few variations on the theme of `rowwise` plus `mutate_at` with no luck. For example:

```
> dat %>% rowwise() %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("sim_")), function(x) { ifelse(cat1 == cat2, NA, x) })
Error in ifelse(cat1 == cat2, x, 0) : object 'cat1' not found
```

What am I missing? I realize that this would be easier if I were to reshape the data from wide to long first, but I'm hoping to learn something about `tidyverse` functions or syntax and find a way to do this without reshaping the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `replace` and `ifelse/replace` are vectorized, so can avoid the `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with('sim')), ~ replace(., cat1 == cat2, NA_real_))
```

Or as these are numeric columns, can directly do the transformation

```
dat %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with('sim')),  ~.* NA^(cat1 == cat2))
```